# Use javascript to append an inline jquery script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use a simple vanilla js script within the page to append some jQuery to the end of the body, where it will come after the jQuery lib load and thus work. I can append js to it fine as shown here..

```
window.onload = function(){
var script   = document.createElement('script');
script.text = "alert('ok');";
document.body.appendChild(script);
};
```

Attemping to append jQuery:

```
window.onload = function(){
var script   = document.createElement('script');
script.text = "$(window).load(function() {";
script.text += "alert('ok');";
script.text += "});";
document.body.appendChild(script);
};
```

Works fine appending vanilla, breaks with any jQuery. Why?

---

*the += instead of one line was one suggested fix to this, but with no luck

**Feels like this should be a duplicate and I'm finding similar issues but not specifically inserting (and triggering, which I realise may be a problem) jQuery.

Comment: You're adding a `load` event to the `window` after the `window` has already loaded, so it won't fire.

Comment: I actually wondered about this and tried running the javascript function on document ready followed by the jquery on window load, however this didn't work for me?

Comment: Could simply be that by the time the `ready` handler runs, the `window` load has already taken place. Is there a reason you want this to be in a `load` handler? You already know the window is loaded.

Comment: Yeah I've tested without the load handler which should mean the vanilla js is run immediately(?). It works with a plain alert but not with the jQuery function still.

Comment: I meant the jQuery load. If you do it without the `window.onload`, then if your script is in the `<head>`, the `document.body` will not yet exist. If you keep the `window.onload = function(){` but make the new script body have just the `alert`, then it should work.

Comment: This must be some kind of system of running arbitrary code, which needs to work whether or not the `window` is loaded. Is that right? If not, why is there a need to coordinate these events?

Comment: I think you are right. My aim is to use the jQuery to insert css into an iframe with a remote source. I'll play around with this but will most likely take a different route as I think there are more efficient ways to do this. Many thanks for your help!